# change permissions to a file and everything inside , recursively

Tags: shell-script, command-line, alias, function

So I want to create an alias called *changeAllPermisions* that accepts one parameter *argument* in such a way that when `changeAllPermissions argument` is called , both Group and Other do not have access to read, write or execute *argument*. If *argument* is a directory, then the permissions will be changed to *argument* as well as everything inside recursively.

Here is what I know

I know how to create an alias, for example

```
alias myAlias=ls
```

I also know how to list files recursively

```
ls -R
```

To change the permissions as stated by my problem, I would do

```
chmod go-rwx
```

But I´m having a hard time putting all this together.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`chmod` already has a recursive flag (`-R`). From the manpage:

```
   -R, --recursive
          change files and directories recursively
```

So, if you wanted a function to do this for you, you could write something like

```
function myFunc() {
    chmod -R go-rwx -- "$1"
}
```

Or an alias:

```
alias myAlias='chmod -R go-rwx'
```

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tested this, but off the top of my head this is what I came up with:

```
alias changeAllPermissions='chmod -R go-rwx $1'
```

The -R option changes permissions recursively.

Comment: What does `$1` do? What difference does it make not to include it? the other person who replied didn't include it

Comment: $1 is a variable representing the first argument being passed to the alias. For example:

`mv ~/myfile ~/backupfile`

~/myfile, being the first argument would be represented by '$1'. ~/backupfile would be represented by '$2'.

I'm guessing he left it out by mistake because otherwise it wouldn't work.

Comment: Actually I tried without it, and it worked

Comment: Good to know. I'm still learning.

Comment: You're mixing up functions and aliases. When defining an alias, the arguments are put at the end; `$1` will be whatever is the shell's positional parameter at the time the alias is expanded (in many situations, this will happen to be empty, so your alias will happen to work). @Haz the `$1` is just a mistake in Graham's answer.